# Populate a Dropdownlist by a value in another dropdownlist ASP.NET

Tags: .net, sql, cascadingdropdown, html-select

Been having some trouble getting a dropdownlist to databind according to a value defined in another dropdownlist.

```
Protected Sub CategoryDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CategoryDDL.SelectedIndexChanged
    qaDDL.Items.Clear()
    qaDDL.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("(New Question)"))

    If CategoryDDL.SelectedValue = "(New Category)" Then
        CategoryName.Text = Nothing
    Else
        Dim filter As String = "categoryID = '" + CategoryDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'"
        Dim dv As DataView = CType(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        dv.RowFilter = filter
        For Each drv As DataRowView In dv
            CategoryName.Text = drv("Name").ToString()
        Next
```

I have tried what is similiar to filling a textbox above, but I don't know how to use this for an array.

```
    dv = CType(SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        For Each drv As DataRowView In dv
            qaDDL.Items.Insert(drv("placement").ToString(), drv("Question").ToString())
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried just using a simple databind with the asp:dropdownlist connected by a datasourceID

```
qaDDL.Databind()
```

Here's what the page looks like.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CategoryDDL" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="300px" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="categoryID" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="(New Category)">(New Category)</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings%>" SelectCommand="SELECT categoryID, Name, placement FROM FAQ_category ORDER BY placement"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="qaDDL" Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Question" DataValueField="faqID">
            <asp:ListItem Value="(New Question)">(New Question)</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings%>" SelectCommand="SELECT faqID, categoryID, Question, Answer FROM FAQ WHERE (categoryID = @categoryID) ORDER BY placement">
```

So what's the best way to do this kind of task?

Comment: I think the tag of html.dropdownlist might be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably subjective, but I would suggest the *easiest* way is to use the AjaxControlToolkit's [CascadingDropDownList](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) extender control as it saves you a postback, and a lot of the work has already been done for you.

Comment: Does it work well for a SQL database? I though that it functioned with XML.

Comment: @Quinson There's a [walkthrough](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Walkthrough/CCDWithDB.aspx) on the website for hooking it up to a SQL database. I'm partway through writing some demo code for you, be tonight before I can finish it though...